# Is there an R function that unifies multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with two factor variables. Those two variables contain identical data except for when some values are missing. I want to end up with a `data.frame` with a third column that contains the complete data.

Example:

```
df<-data.frame(UID = 1:8,
               A = c("blue", NA, "blue", NA, "green", NA, "green", "green"),
               B = c("blue", "blue", NA, "blue", NA, "green", NA, "green"))
```

I am looking for the third column to equal;

```
df$C<-c(rep("blue", 4), rep("green", 4))
```

I have tried using `tidyr::unite` to no avail. I know this is probably a bad idea, LOL. I figure there is either a really simple answer or that it is not possible, LOL. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df <-  df %>% 
          mutate(C = coalesce(A, B))
```

Comment: OMG! I knew it was going to be something super simple. I was unfamiliar with this function, so thank you so much for answering!